# Truncating file when using csvreader

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that is 2.2M lines. However, when I try and read it with `csvreader` it truncates it to 170,000 lines. Why does this occur and how can I load the entire file into a csv reader?

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open(filepath), delimiter='|')
print len(list(reader))
174177
```

I confirmed in the file it is in fact more than 2M lines, so the file itself is not truncating.

Comment: How much memory would that take up?

Comment: @PeterWood -- what would be the best way to see that? `top` ?

Comment: That or the back of a napkin.

Comment: Why do you need the whole file?

Comment: What does `print sum(1 for _ in reader)` produce?

Comment: I'm thinking along the same line as @jedwards here... text *lines* aren't the same as CSV *rows* depending on quoting - also, use `open(filepath, 'rb')` to read it in binary mode instead of the default text mode

Comment: @jedwards I also get 174177 for that.

Comment: @David542 open it in binary mode, try again, see what you get :)

Comment: I'll hazard a guess that you're on windows, and you've got an EOF char somewhere...

Comment: Then your data would seem malformed / you're reading it improperly / lines of file != rows as Jon Clements points out.  If it returned 2.2M I would say it hit some memory limit when trying to read the entire contents into a list.  But the `sum(1 for _ in  reader)` wouldn't have that limitation.

Comment: @jedwards it looks like it's a malformed file. Thanks for the help troubleshooting.